# Canvas Drawing creating System.OutOfMemoryException Win Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am developing a windows phone 8 app, I use Rectangle and Lines to draw a graph inside a Canvas placed inside a ScrollViewer.

But during the drawing I am facing System.OutOfMemoryException during drawing of the canvas( graph may go more than 3 times the size of the screen)

I have placed the Canvas inside a ScrollViewer. When I remove the ScrollViewer the issue does'nt occur but I am unable to scroll the Canvas even if I set the property `Scrollviwer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibilty = Visible`.

```
<ScrollViewer Name="MainScrollViewer"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"   HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.RowSpan="2" >
    <Canvas x:Name="MainCanvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Tap="OnCanvasTap" >
        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform CenterX="100" CenterY="75" />
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
    </Canvas>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I have also tried using `GC.Collect` and `Canvas.Children.Clear()` where I am drawing but even then the issue persist.

Comment: Use a smaller canvas?

Comment: Thanks for response, I am drawing a graph using canvas, sometime the graph is very large based on the duration. I am using Line drawing. Any better way to handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a large canvas inside a scrollable div to contain all of the graphics you can use a smaller canvas, optimally max of the actual screen size (not the graphics) and then use translate the canvas and redraw the graphics at the translated position.

Optimally because if you have a huge canvas and only see 25% of then the other 75% is wasted memory.

By using the canvas as a "peephole" combined with translation you will get the same result on screen (you see 100% of what is possible to see at one time) and you don't need to worry about your graphics as this will be clipped automatically by the canvas.

You can attach translation to mouse/touch drag-and-move operation or make "virtual" scroll-bars if that is preferred.

Comment: Thanks Ken. I followed your suggestion, and drawing only the double of the screen size graph, for rest I am clearing the canvas and drawing the next part. :)